# Issue with NonStrictExpections to Expectations conversion in junit test cases

Tags: junit, jmockit, expectations

Here is my sample code example, which starts failing when I made jmockit update related changes.

```
class A {

    public static boolean validate(String name, int age, boolean flag) {
        boolean result = false;
        //actual code
        return result;
    }
}

class B {
    public void cal() {
        if (A.validate(name, age, flag)) {
            // some calculations
        }
    }
}

class TestB {
    public B b;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        b = new B();
    }

    @Test
    public void testCal() {
        new Expectations() {
            {
                A.validate(anyString, anyInt, anyBoolean);
                times= -1;
                result = Boolean.TRUE;
            }};

        b.cal();

        new Verifications() {
            {
                A.validate(anyString, anyInt, anyBoolean);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This is failing with error

```
mockit.internal.UnexpectedInvocation: Unexpected invocation of:
A#validate(String name, int age, boolean flag)
```

I just changed NonStrictExpectations block to Expectations block, because latest jmockit dont support 
NonStrictExpectations block.

```
new NonStrictExpectations() {
    {
        A.validate(anyString, anyInt, anyBoolean);
        returns(Boolean.TRUE);
    }
};
```

With this block everything works fine.

Please let me know where is the issue?

Comment: For starters, the `times = -1` statement doesn't make sense (at least to me). You're specifying to expect -1 calls to the validate method, which is weird, probably that's why it's saying that it doesn't expect a call to it. Also, do not mix expectations and verifications for the same method, I think it does not work well. Usually if the method returns something, use expectations, if not, verfications, but not both at the same time. Try deleting both the times=-1 and the verifications part.

Comment: I thought `times = -1` means we can get call or not. But I agree we dont need verification here.

Comment: In the original JMockit docs, there's no mention to negative `times` values. For optional calls you should use `minTimes` and `maxTimes` values. For example with `maxTimes=1` you could have an optional.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks. Can you add this as a answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, using a negative value for the `times` is not a valid value.

Second, if what you need is to have an optional call, you should use the `minTimes` and `maxTimes` variables. In your case with `maxTimes = 1` you will achieve an optional mocked call.